# How can I contract canvas by a view padding?

Tags: java, android, canvas, ondraw

I'm building a custom view, in which I override onDraw method.

Is there a way to contract canvas (received as an argument in onDraw) by this view padding values?

And to answer any possible questions about padding itself - In my case, I cannot use margins. I need to use paddings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every view has getPaddingTop/Bottom/Left/Right() methods which will give you the value for each padding.

When you draw with your canvas, you'll need to make sure that you always draw within these limits:

```
minX = getPaddingLeft()
maxX = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()
minY = getPaddingTop()
maxY = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom()
```

**Edit**:

If you want to limit what area on the canvas can be drawn on, try using the following call on Canvas:

```
canvas.clipRect(minX, minY, maxX, maxY, Region.Op.REPLACE);
```

Anything that is drawn outside of these limits will be ignored.

Keep in mind that this will work well until you start performing transformations on the canvas (e.g. translate). Once you start doing this, things begin getting a bit weird, and you may need to alter the clipRect during runtime.

Comment: I know that and I kinda can't use this approach either... To simplify explanation let's say the drawing itself is being performed by a third-part library, and I can't really interact with the drawing bounds themselves. I can only give this library my canvas, and wait for magic to happen. Therefore my question is about contracting the canvas...

Comment: Yep that's what I needed, thanks. I'll just edit your answer so the values works correctly with clipRect.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a bitmap with the inner size (without the padding), pass that to the library,and the draw the bitmap onto your canvas

Another option is to translate the canvas by using contact() with a matrix that moves the canvas by the padding left and top. Also clip the canvas so that the library can not draw on top of teh bottom and right padding